# In SQL, can you write a where clause, if a date range falls within a date range

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, date-range

I work with patient information, which contains an admit date and a discharge date. I have a query that I need to add a WHERE clause that would only identify patients within a date range.

For instance, I want to pull all patients that where in the hospital from 5-1-2021 to 5-31-2021. This would include patients with an admit/discharge (and anything in between) at any point in May.

```
Hospital 1      
Patient Admit_Date  Disch_Date
1       4/5/2021    5/20/2021
2       5/6/2021    5/10/2021
3      4/10/2021    4/22/2021
4      4/19/2021    7/5/2021
5       6/1/2021    6/7/2021
```

I want to only include patients that were in Hospital 1 from 5/1/2021 to 5/31/2021, so it would yield this table:

```
Hospital 1      
Patient Admit_Date  Disch_Date
1       4/5/2021    5/20/2021
2       5/6/2021    5/10/2021
4      4/19/2021    7/5/2021
```

I tried using a BETWEEN clause, but it didn't include patients like patient #4 who were admitted before May and Discharge after May, but were in the hospital in May. Basically I'm trying to pull a census, so I can say there were XX number of patients on May 4th or May 22nd etc. but for all of May (or any month for that matter).

Thanks!!!

Comment: A patient would be in hospital in May if they were admitted on or before the end of May and discharged on or after the start of May.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Columns Admit_Date and Disch_Date data type?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio. And Dates are CONVERT(date,Admit_Date,102). Basically just dates, but I could convert to dates later I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to pick anyone who was admitted before the end of the month and who was discharged after the start of the month
Use something like this in your where clause

```
where 
  Admit_Date <= '2021-05-31' and 
  Disch_Date >= '2021-05-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```sql
SELECT *
FROM event_ 
WHERE start_ < '2021-06-01' 
AND end_ !< '2021-05-01'
;
```

## Half-Open

Generally best to define spans of time as Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So the month of May starts with May 1 and runs up to, but does not include, the first of June.

## Avoid `BETWEEN`

Do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN` for this work. That command is Fully-Closed rather than Half-Open.

## *Overlaps* test

Your goal involves an *overlaps* test, where the row’s date range is neither entirely before, nor entirely after, the target date range. In other words, the two ranges share some part of the time-line.

So the logic is:

- row start is before target end, AND
- row end is equal to or later than target beginning.

In standard SQL code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM event_ 
WHERE start_ < '2021-06-01' 
AND end_ >= '2021-05-01'
;
```

Another way of saying “is equal to or later than is “not before”. Some databases support the use of `!<` though that operator may not be defined in the SQL standard.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM event_ 
WHERE start_ < '2021-06-01' 
AND end_ !< '2021-05-01'
;
```

Comment: Please, use standard operators. `!<` will raise a syntax error on most dbms's.

Comment: @jarth I added a note about that. Thank you.

Comment: A note about `!<` might not be enough, a link to some docs, in this case MS-SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-less-than-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

For the duration of an admission to have fallen within the month of May the admission must have started before the end of May, and ended after the start of May. This "feels" off, but you can see the logic of it if you draw out the timelines yourself with a pen and paper.

The requisite query is then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM admissions
WHERE admit_date <= '2021-05-31' 
AND disch_date >= '2021-05-01';
```

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL use double quotes for identifiers, which here would mean `"2021-05-31"` is read as a column named `2021-05-31`. Single quotes are used for date/time and string literals. (However, a few dbms products have other ways to do this - unfortunately.)